# Install glibc 2.15 in Red Hat 6.5

Tags: linux, opencv, redhat, glibc, yum

I'm using openCV in my project. When I've tested in Red Hat instance, I have exception " /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found".
So, how I can install glibc 2.15 in Red Hat? 
I fond [rpm](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit))(not 2.15(I hope new version can help me)), but I need some dependencies. Can I install glibc from some repo?

thx!

Comment: Red Hat 6.5?  This was released in 2000 or so... I am in doubt that you will be able to install some actual library on it (kernel requirements, archive formats, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I install glibc from some repo?

Not likely: distributions usually don't ever update the major/minor version of glibc from the one they originally shipped with, because the likelihood of breaking applications is too great.

You may have to build glibc-2.15, or better current glibc-2.24 from source and install it into non-default location. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).

Answer (score 0):

If you are registered to satellite , Just run :

## yum install glibc

this should take care of all .
If you are installing using rpms manually, you need dependent rpms as well.

Hope this helps.. Good luck.