# Making VS Code Remote extension work with GLIBC 2.17 installed in non standard locations

Tags: visual-studio-code, centos, vscode-remote

I'm trying to use [VSCode Remote extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) to connect to a remote host that runs on RHEL/CentOS 6, but it fails to connect since CentOS 6 ships with GLIBC 2.12 and GLIBCXX 3.4.1. As mentioned in [this post](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/linux#_tips-by-linux-distribution), in order to get the extension to work, the workaround is to install GLIBC>=2.17 and GLIBCXX>=3.4.18.

Unfortunately, I don't have sudo access for the server, so I won't be able to update these libraries using the bash script provided in the link. Also, in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38723864/3187043), the author says not to update the system GLIBC since it can break down system applications. That being said, I've tried something different --  I extracted those rpm packages, as described in [this blog](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/10/13/inspect-extract-contents-rpm-packages/), inside my home folder. I've then updated the env variables `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in ~/.bash_profile to point to these new locations. But the node binary (in VS Code Remote) still can't find these libraries.

Is there a way to let the node binary know where to look for these libraries? More precisely, can someone explain how I can make this extension work without sudo access?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to work by installing gcc and glibc using Linuxbrew. See this post for more details: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/103#issuecomment-546551293.

Couple of things to take note of:

1. Node binary versions in VS Code Server may vary between commits. In the GitHub comment above, the author uses node@10 -- you may replace it with node@12; everything would still work.
2. Make sure glibc and gcc are properly installed using linuxbrew. This step is key.